# Jasmine compile/create components acting weirdly with beforeAll/beforeEach

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm writing some unit test for an application of mine, and I came across a pretty weird situation.
I built an angular app, and I am using karma&jasmine for unit/integration tests.

Here's the deal:
I wrote this code

```
describe("Body Container component", () => {
    let component: BodyContainerComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<BodyContainerComponent>;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        getTestBed().configureTestingModule({
            imports: [AppTestingModule]
        });
        await getTestBed().compileComponents();
        fixture = getTestBed().createComponent(BodyContainerComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

And it works fine, tests are compiled and executed correctly (and pass).
They do take a while though, I guess because each and everytime testingModule is configured back again and components compiled.

So a tried to change it this way:

```
 beforeAll(async () => {
    getTestBed().resetTestingModule();
    getTestBed().configureTestingModule({
        imports: [AppTestingModule]
    });
    await getTestBed().compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(async () => {
    fixture = getTestBed().createComponent(BodyContainerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

This version of the same logic/API called though fails on getTestBed().createComponent, fails with:

```
 Error: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive BodyContainerComponent.
    error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true })
        at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:2430:1)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveSummary (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:18535:1)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.getComponentFactory (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:25979:1)
        at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.getComponentFactory (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js?:162:1)
        at TestingCompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/testing.js.TestingCompilerImpl.getComponentFactory (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/testing.js?:110:1)
        at TestBedViewEngine.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/testing.js.TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/testing.js?:1905:1)
        at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/src/test/integration/app/components/body-container.integration-spec.ts?:21:32)
        at step (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js?:97:1)
        at Object.next (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js?:78:45)
        at http://localhost:9876/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js?:71:1
```

I tried various iterations and changes to make it work, but the error persists. 
After some analysis I can say:
1- async/await works fine, beforeach is called only after beforeAll finished
2- every single test give that error above, even the first one (which is very weird, because logically the first one shouldnt change an inch between the 2 versions

One thing I noticed is that the first version tests are excecuted randomly whereas the second version seems to follow an order. 
The async on the beforeach of the second version doesnt change anything, also i tried calling various reset/destroy methods but none seems to contribute.

Do you know why this happens?
It's ok if it cant be resolved, it is after all a minor optimization while looking at the whole build process, I am more so curious why this happens.

EDIT: After additionals analysis, by looking at the testBed instance, I noticed that the "beforeEach only" implementation has

```
TestBedViewEngine{_instantiated: false, _compiler: TestingCompilerImpl{_compiler: CompilerImpl{_metadataResolver: ..., _delegate: ..., injector: ...}, _directiveResolver: MockDirectiveResolver{_reflector: ..., _directives: ...}, _pipeResolver: MockPipeResolver{_reflector: ..., _pipes: ...}, _moduleResolver: MockNgModuleResolver{_reflector: ..., _ngModules: ...}, _overrider: MetadataOverrider{_references: ...}}, _moduleRef: null, _moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory_{moduleType: function DynamicTestModule() { ... }, _bootstrapComponents: [], _ngModuleDefFactory: function(_l) { ... }}, _compilerOptions: [], _moduleOverrides: [], _componentOverrides: [], _directiveOverrides: [], _pipeOverrides: [], _providers: [], _declarations: [], _imports: [function AppTestingModule() { ... }], _schemas: [], _activeFixtures: [], _testEnvAotSummaries: function () { ... }, _aotSummaries: [], _templateOverrides: [], _isRoot: true, _rootProviderOverrides: [], platform: PlatformRef{_injector: StaticInjector{parent: ..., source: ..., _records: ...}, _modules: [], _destroyListeners: [], _destroyed: false}, ngModule: function BrowserDynamicTestingModule() { ... }}
```

whereas the beforeAll has:

```
TestBedViewEngine{_instantiated: false, _compiler: null, _moduleRef: null, _moduleFactory: null, _compilerOptions: [], _moduleOverrides: [], _componentOverrides: [], _directiveOverrides: [], _pipeOverrides: [], _providers: [], _declarations: [], _imports: [], _schemas: [], _activeFixtures: [], _testEnvAotSummaries: function () { ... }, _aotSummaries: [], _templateOverrides: [], _isRoot: true, _rootProviderOverrides: [], platform: PlatformRef{_injector: StaticInjector{parent: ..., source: ..., _records: ...}, _modules: [], _destroyListeners: [], _destroyed: false}, ngModule: function BrowserDynamicTestingModule() { ... }}
```

The big difference that I can see by this output is the _compiler, which is null and instantiated respectively.
This TestBed "snapshot" was taken just before the createComponent call

Comment: Apparently getTestBed() loses states (or changes instance, or whatever) when you exit the beforeAll call.  In fact, you I move the logging output inside the beforeAll, I noticed _compiler not being null, whereas it's null in beforeEach

Comment: sadly this loss happens even if you first assign testBed to a local variable, and doesnt change anything if you use async() function helper instead of typescript async keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found out the issue can be found here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12409

Basically, to sum up, angular actually re-define beforeEach function, adding some very opinionated behavior. Specifically, it's written right here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/testing/src/before_each.ts#L24

For that reason, the test module configured in the beforeAll it's actually reset in the beforeEach (before the createComponent call).
Instead using only beforeEach actually works because the module is configured after the reset call.

So, either you use beforeEach as intended, sacrificing speed (angular opinion is that provided services should be fresh at each test, which doesnt make sense for stateless stuff) or you could opt in for 2 different solutions:
1) re-define again global beforeEach, reinstating it to default and then put back angular behavior: this is of course an hack and is quite unstable and throws random errors since angular assumes modules are fresh for its own internals
2) don't use beforeEach at all, configure the module in the beforeAll and than demand all the beforeEach activities to a custom function which you call on each it statement